# Is it possible to have function variables already include arguments?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$posted_on = new DateTime($date_started);
$today = new DateTime('today');
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
$myFormat = 'format(\'Y-m-d\')';

if($posted_on->{$myFormat} == $today->{$myFormat}) {
    $post_date = 'Today';
}
elseif($posted_on->{$myFormat} == $yesterday->{$myFormat}) {
    $post_date = 'Yesterday';
}
else{
    $post_date = $posted_on->format('F jS, Y');
}

echo 'Started '.$post_date;
```

As you can see I'm trying to use "format('Y-m-d')" many times, and don't want to type it in multiple places, so I'm trying to simply put it in a variable and use that. However, I get a notice: Message: Undefined property: DateTime::$format('Y-m-d')

What would be the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: Yet another "how can I reduce the number of keystrokes I have to type at the expense of making my code unreadable" question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can curry the function:

```
$myFormat = function($obj) {return $obj->format("Y-m-d");};

if( $myFormat($posted_on) == $myFormat($today))
```

Or more cleanly:

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
    public function format($fmt="Y-m-d") {
        return parent::format($fmt);
    }
}
$posted_on = new MyDateTime($date_started);
$today = new MyDateTime("today");
$yesterday = new MyDateTime("yesterday");

if( $posted_on->format() == $today->format()) {...
```

Comment: Worth +1 just to see a sensible answer to the question

Comment: Better change to public function format($format = "Y-m-d") because later in code format called with a different argument: $posted_on->format('F jS, Y')

Comment: This is a superb answer. I will be using this not for this specific situation, but in general in my coding. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

```
$myFormat = 'Y-m-d';
...
$today->format($myFormat);
...
```

Comment: I take it that it's not possible to do what I intended then, to include the function itself. I was just curious about that. Thank you.

Comment: @user371699 Yes it's possible but, it's also horrible. Don't do stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$posted_on = new DateTime($date_started);
$today = new DateTime('today');
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
$myFormat = 'Y-m-d';

if($posted_on->format($myFormat) == $today->format($myFormat)) {
    $post_date = 'Today';
}
elseif($posted_on->format($myFormat) == $yesterday->($myFormat)) {
    $post_date = 'Yesterday';
}
else{
    $post_date = $posted_on->format('F jS, Y');
}

echo 'Started '.$post_date;
```

That is the best you can do. I would put the format somewhere in a constant or a config file but w/e. What you are trying to do is possible but it's so horrible that I actually started crying when I read it.

Also in this case I would do something like this

```
$interval   = $posted_on->diff(new DateTime('today'));
$postAge    = $interval->format('%d'); // Seems to be the best out of many horrible options
if($postAge == 1)
{
    $post_date = 'Today';
}
else if($postAge == 2)
{
    $post_date = 'Yesterday';
}
else
{
    $post_date = $posted_on->format('F jS, Y');
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I would love to understand *why* it would be horrible, and why "$interval->format('%d')" would be the "best out of many horrible options". What is bad about that? And last question, if $posted_on is also TODAY, why wouldn't the difference between the two be 0 days?

Comment: Yeah you should use 0 and 1, not 1 and 2 :(

Comment: Well what you would want to do is something like $interval->getDays() but instead PHP only alows you to do $interval->d which is public and modifyable. (Which in turn makes me want to puke).